Pyinstaller: problem with imports and reading/writting files
I am creating a discord bot for a, private, small server, with friends. I would like the bot to be runable by any of my friends, none of whom know much about programming.
My idea was to bundle it up on a .exe, using pyinstaller.
It's my first time using pyinstaller so I might be missing something obvious.
I expected to be able to just double click it and let it run in the background.
The issue is, as far as I've put together, that the bot reads and writes data from local files, which doesn't seem to translate well into the packaged .exe.
Beside that, many python modules, made by me, are rising errors when imported, not found.
What I've tried:
--add-data "Source;dir"
The files are copied well, but any bot commands that accesses them doesn't work.
using this, I "solved" the import errors of my own modules, though I am skeptical.
--paths=.venv\Lib\site-packages
Some of the import errors were solved but others remain, as shown in the image.
Error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Files...
File  "asyncio\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'asyncio.base_events'

asyncio is installed in the virtual environment I used.
The spec file:
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


a = Analysis(
    ['main.py'],
    pathex=['path-to-app-root\\.venv\\Lib\\site-packages'],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[('static', 'static'), ('mutable', 'mutable'),  ('moreCogs', 'moreCogs'), ('musicbot', 'musicbot'), ('snapcogs2', 'snapcogs2')],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
    optimize=0,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='discordbot',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)


Edit: some clarifications and added the error message.
Edit: project structure:
This is my project structure:

main.py-dir
 ├───moreCogs
 │   ├───Casino
 │   │   └───__pycache__
 │   ├───Economy
 │   │   └───__pycache__
 │   ├───Poll
 │   │   └───__pycache__
 │   ├───utils
 │   │   └───__pycache__
 │   ├───Weas
 │   │   └───__pycache__
 │   └───__pycache__
 ├───musicbot
 │   ├───config
 │   │   ├───cookies
 │   │   └───__pycache__
 │   ├───musicbot
 │   │   ├───commands
 │   │   │   └───__pycache__
 │   │   ├───generated
 │   │   ├───plugins
 │   │   │   └───__pycache__
 │   │   └───__pycache__
 │   └───ui
 ├───mutable
 ├───Cogs
 │   ├───Fun
 │   │   └───__pycache__
 │   ├───Poll
 │   │   └───__pycache__
 │   └───__pycache__
 ├───static
 │   ├───css
 │   ├───datasets
 │   └───roulette
 └───__pycache__


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Yeah I thought that might be a malpractice, but the error pops for just a moment and I can't copy it.

You do have a screenshot...if you can't copy-paste the error message, just rewrite it as text.

As said above, ideally the image should be text but also make sure to format the image as an image rather than a link: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#images

Fixed. Thanks for the advice.
